# Ubuntu 12.04 DVD Playback

Tags: 12.04, encryption, dvd

I am getting the classic error DVDs cannot be played because the DVD is encrypted and DVD decryption library is not installed. I have followed the directions to install a host of utilities that culminate with this command:

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

However this command is failing with this:

```
    --2013-07-31 19:35:10--  http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/precise/free/binary-amd64/Packages
Resolving packages.medibuntu.org (packages.medibuntu.org)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `packages.medibuntu.org'
Dynamic fetch failed; Falling back to static fetch
--2013-07-31 19:35:30--  http://packages.medibuntu.org/pool/free/libd/libdvdcss/libdvdcss2_1.2.10-0.2medibuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Any ideas would be appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Medibuntu's repository is down:

[image]

I'm afraid you'll have to wait until it come back up.

Comment: @Wjdavis5 Repository is up now. Please try again.

Comment: It downloaded, still cannot read dvds though